# Jquery Fly To Cart not Flying Properly on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add a fly to cart function 'fly to cart on click' and it works perfectly on desktop view. But when I switch to mobile for some reason it flys to the left side of my screen where my cart icon is not at. It would basically fly to the 'hamburger menu.' Not quite sure why it's doing that....

I got the code from this code pen:
https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/tEeDn

Thanks in advance for any help!

This code below is for a collection page.

```
    <div class="product_wrap">
      <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="grid__image">
        {% if template == 'index'%}
          <img class="firstProdPic" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
        {% else %}
          <img class="firstProdPic" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
        {% endif %}
        <div name="secomapp-fg-image-{{ product.id }}" style="display: none;"> {{ "icon-freegift.png" | asset_url | img_tag: "", "sca-fg-img-collect" }} </div>
        <div class="sca-fg-cat-list" style="display:none;" name="secomapp-fg-data-{{ product.id }}" prod-show='list'> </div>
      </a>
      {%comment%}
      <div class="view-details-btn">
        {%comment%}<a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="btn btn3">View Details</a>{%endcomment%}
    <!--     changed the above part because it was throwing different urls ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->
    <!--     <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="btn btn3">View Details</a> -->
        {% if product.images[1] %}
        <a href="{{product.url}}">
          <img class="secondProdPic" src="{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.images[1].alt | escape }}" />
        </a>
       {%endif%}

      </div>
      {%endcomment%}
      {% if settings.quick_view_enabled %}
        <a href="#product-{{ product.id }}" class="quick-view-link">Quick View</a>
        {% include 'quick-view' %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if settings.collection_layout == 'hover' %}
        <div class="product_overlay">
          <div class="overlay-table">
            <div class="overlay-inner">
        {% else %}
            <div class="product_info{% if settings.collection_layout == 'fancy' %} fancy{% endif %}">
        {% endif %}
              <a href="{{product.url}}"><p class="product_title">{{ product.title | split: ' - ' | first }}</p></a>
              <p class="tags" style="color: {{productColor}};">{{ helps | upcase }}</p>
              <div class="product-meta">
                {% if settings.show_product_price %}
                  <p class="product_price">
              {% unless variant.metafields.secomapp.freegifts %}
              {% unless variant.title contains '(Freegifts)' %} 
                    {% if on_sale %}
                      {% if bold_price_varies %}
                        {% assign sale_price = bold_price | money %}
                        <strong>{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t: price: sale_price }}</strong>
                      {% else %}
                        <span class="comparePrice">{{ bold_compare_at_price_min | money }}</span>
                        <span>{{ bold_price | money }}</span>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                      {% if bold_price_varies %}
                        {% assign price = bold_price | money %}
                        {% if settings.product_varyprice == 'from' %}
                          {{ 'products.general.from_text_html' | t: price: price }}
                        {% elsif settings.product_varyprice == 'plus' %}
                          {{ bold_price | money }}+
                        {% else %}

                              {{ bold_price_min | money }} - {{ bold_price_max | money }}

                        {% endif %}
                      {% else %}
                        {{ bold_price | money }}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
               {%endunless%}
              {%endunless%}
                  </p>
                {% endif %}
                <!--<p><span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span></p>-->
                  <div class="yotpo bottomLine"
                    style="display:inline-block;"
                    data-product-id="{{ product.id }}"
                    data-url="{{ product.url }}">
                  </div>
                <form method="post" action="/cart/add" class="productCoreForm">
                  <div class="product-single__add-to-cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ bold_selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}" />

    <!-- ***************************Took out the plus and minus sign from add to cart button -->
                    {% comment %}{% if settings.collection_add_cart_quantity %}{% if settings.collection_add_cart_quantity %}{% include 'quantity' with 'collection' %}{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endcomment %}
    <!-- ***************************took outthe plus and minus sign from add to cart button -->

                    <div class="submit-container">
                      <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="back" />
                      <input type="submit" name="add" id="addtacart" class="btn {{settings.product_page_button_type}} productCoreBtn {{product.handle}} pcoreButton" data-price="{{ current_variant.price | money_without_currency }}" value="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
      {% if settings.collection_layout == 'hover'%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% else %}
      </div>
      {% endif %} 
    </div>
    <script>
      // fly to cart code *********************************************************************
      $('.pcoreButton').on('click', function () {
            console.log('firing addtocart');
            var cart = $('.cart-link');
        console.log(cart);
            var imgtodrag = $(this).parents('.product_wrap').find('.firstProdPic');
            if (imgtodrag.length) {
                var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                    .offset({
                    top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                    left: imgtodrag.offset().left
                })
                    .css({
                    'opacity': '0.5',
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'height': '150px',
                        'width': '150px',
                        'z-index': '100'
                })
                    .appendTo($('body'))
                    .animate({
                    'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                        'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                        'width': 75,
                        'height': 75
                }, 1000);

                imgclone.animate({
                    'width': 0,
                        'height': 0
                }, function () {
                    $(this).detach()
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The Code below is for my site-header where my cart icon is:

```
            <header class="site-header is-moved-by-drawer" role="banner">
            {% if settings.top_bar_show %}
              <div class="top-bar">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="top-bar-inner">
                    {% if settings.top_bar_text != '' %}
                    <div class="top-bar-content">
                      {% if customer %}
                        <div class="top-bar-text"  style="display:table;font-size:0.8rem;">{{ settings.top_bar_text }}</div>
                      {% else %}
                        <div class="top-bar-text"  style="display:table;font-size:0.8rem;">{%include 'topbar_newsletter' %}</div>
                      {%endif%}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="top-bar-meta right medium-down--hide">
                      <div class="header-right">
                        {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
                          {% if customer %}
                            <a href='' style="text-transform:none;">You have (<span data-lion-points>0</span>) Guru Points</a>
                            {{ 'Log out' | customer_logout_link }}
                            <a href="/account" class="account-link"><span>Account</span> {% include 'svg_icon' with 'account' %}</a>
                          {% else %}
                            <a href='' style="text-transform:none;">You have (<span data-lion-points>0</span>) Guru Points</a>
                            {{ 'Log in' | customer_login_link }}
                            {% if shop.customer_accounts_optional %}
                              {{ 'Register' | customer_register_link }}
                            {% endif %}
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <a href="/cart" class="cart-link site-header__cart-toggle js-drawer-open-right" aria-controls="CartDrawer" aria-expanded="false">{% include 'svg_icon' with 'cart' %}<span class="cart-count">{{ cart.item_count }}</span></a>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="site-nav--mobile mobile-cart-btn post-medium--hide text-right">
            <span id="mobileSearch" class="icon icon-search searchIcon"></span>

            <a href="/cart" class="js-drawer-open-right site-nav__link cart-link" aria-controls="CartDrawer" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="cart-svg">
                {% include 'svg_icon' with 'cart' %}
                <span class="cart-count">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </div>
          </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because the .cart-link for some reason was not being read by the .offset().left or .offset().top.
Console.logged it and console said it was undefined. 
Went up the tree and called a parent div and it gave me a value. 
However it would still fire differently on mobile so I added a query to check for mobile window size and grabbed the mobile carts element to find the offset and then it works perfect.